# Returning a NULL when return type is not a pointer

Tags: c++

I have a function defined as

```
ClassType f(int i) {
  if (...) return NULL;
  ...
  ClassType obj;
  return obj;
}
```

I am curious why a "NULL" could be legally accepted when a class type is required as return type? I think NULL is usually defined by Macro as a synonym of '0'. Could someone explain the rationale behind this? Thanks!

update:

The class is defined as:

```
class ClassType {
public:
  ClassType() {};
  ClassType(char* s) {...};
...
}
```

One more question, Does c++ do implicit conversion when return by value?

Thanks!

Comment: how is `ClassType` defined? , i;m interested in the constructor ?

Comment: @Raxvan implicit conversion you think ?

Comment: @Nik yes , implicit conversion.

Comment: @JASON add debug message in ClassType(char* s) {...}; and check for yourself what is happening or debug the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ClassType {
public:
  ClassType() {};
  ClassType(char* s) {...}; // <<-----
}
```

The constructor that I marked is used when you say `return NULL;`. The value is implicitly convertible to `char*` (`NULL` is usualy defined as `0` and that's a valid pointer value).

> One more question, Does c++ do implicit conversion when returning a value?

Yes, as it has to construct an object of suitable type.

Comment: To add to that, you can prevent this from happening with the `explicit` keyword in the constructor declaration.

Comment: `NULL` can't be `(void*)0` in C++. It has to be an integral constant expression with value `0` or `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, in this case you *can* return `NULL`, as the compiler will then use the `ClassType(char* s)` constructor with `NULL` passed as the constructor argument.

But generally, for cases like these you might want to pass the object as a reference argument to the function, and then return boolean `true` or `false` is the function was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Null is a macro that is defined with `0` which is an integer value. If the `ClassType` has a constructor that accepts integers,or pointers then the compiler will automatically convert the integer 0 to `ClassType` :

```
class ClassType 
{
public:
    ClassType(const int);
};
```

If the class doens't have a constructor that can take 0 then the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: `NULL` isn't necessarily just `0`.

Comment: @chris the c version defines it as ((void*)0) but there you can't have constructors that could be used for implicit conversion. Some compilers might treat NULL differently , but the implicit conversions should still work. nullptr was added in c++ 11 as far as i know to solve this issue.

Comment: C99 defines `NULL` as a null pointer constant. That's only one possibility for a null pointer constant. But yes, `nullptr` was introduced to clear this up. An interesting point to note is that `#define NULL nullptr` is legal for an implementation AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Not accurately an answer to your question, but in general, to indicate optional return values, consider the following.

---

For cases where an optional return value makes sense, you might look into `boost::optional`, and C++14 will possibly define `std::optional` (based on the boost-library).

Additional return values in diguise, like `bool`s indicating success, often come at the burden that you cannot *initialize* an object only in case you *can*, and if you want to return an optional value for which there is no default construction, you either can't, or you have to pass around reference-pointers, and then have to check pointer at the called site, etc.:

```
std::optional<Intensity> sample_spectrum (float); // clean and concise

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool sample_spectrum (Intensity &out); // either not possible or you
                                       // have a wasted initialization

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool sample_spectrum (Intensity *& out) { // now you have two problems
    if (!out) throw std::logic_error(""); // I
    ....
}
....
    try { .... } catch (...) { .... }     // II

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Intensity *sample_spectrum(float) ; // please no

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::shared_ptr<Intensity> 
   sample_spectrum(float); // just use std/boost::optional
```